# Different colours to outline on left, right, top and bottom on svg text

Tags: css, svg

The following code displays SVG text with dashed outline of the the width 2px. I want to make its left outline of green colour by adding a css class. Similarly for other sides want to change colour of outline using css class instead of standard Black colour. I tried giving border but was not getting reflected. Please guide how to do.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <style>
    #abc { outline:dashed; outline-width:2px;}
    </style>
    <svg height="100" width="200">
      <text x="10" y="25" fill="red" id="abc">I love SVG!</text>
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is not possible with styling. you'll have to draw the borders with paths.

Comment: you will need: 1. getComputedTextLength() or getBbox() in javascript. 2. draw lines around the text using the size of the text element calculated in javascript. 3. set the color of each line as you like.

Answer (score -2):

please see this code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
#abc { outline:dashed; outline-width:2px; outline-color:green}
</style>
<svg height="100" width="200">
  <text x="10" y="25" fill="red" id="abc">I love SVG!</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution changed colour of all sides to green. I need to change colour of only the user specified side which could be either left, right top or bottom